# Check the flow of execution of a c# program

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

I have downloaded a C# project from the internet and I want to make some changes to it so that it suits my requirement. However, I cannot figure out how the program actually works. To be precise, I would like to know the starting point of the application and want to execute it step by step till it finishes execution. I'm new to the .Net environment. Previously, I used f7 key on Turbo C++ to do the same. I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Comment: what kind of your project, web, console .etc.

Answer (score 3):

When you have opened the solution in Visual Studio Press **F10** to start Debugging. That will redirect you to the starting point in your project.

Comment: pay attention: with F10 start, no F5, or F6. (This is available for VisualStudio 2010 and 2012. Other older version, i don't know)

Answer (score 0):

Start program and hit `pause`, so it will pause in starting point, in the "cycle" of program, if this is an executable.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `void Main()` function, set a breakpoint there and then use `F10` and `F11` to debug your way through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the entry point in the properties of the project.